If $y = \arctan\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}}, x>0, $then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is
I eliminated $x$ terms by doing $\frac{dy}{dx} $= $\frac{1}{1+x^{(2/3)}.1/3x^{(-2/3)}}.$
Now what else to do?

Please elaborate your work and $y=\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\implies y'=\frac{1}{1+x^2}||,, y=x^n\implies y'=nx^{n-1}$ + all the best with your exam!

bro this is a JEE ADVANCED QUESTION

Where the question came from is something you should include in the question. While on the topic of ways to improve your question - please format it using MathJax - it is currently quite unreadable.

@RohitSrivastava, best case utilize this required $\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)$ for $xy>-1$, and do not worry about whether it is a mains/adv category question :)

If this is a jee advance question, I'm pretty sure there must be a good enough explanation in some website.

y= $arctan\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}}$
$\Rightarrow tan \ y=\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(tan \ y)= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}})$
$\Rightarrow sec^{2} \ y.y^{'}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}})$
W.K.T,
$$sec^{2}y=1+tan^{2}y$$
Now solve the RHS and use the [W.K.T] and get the answer.
$\bullet$ Here $y^{'}$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$
Solution:

If $y = \arctan\frac{x^{1/3}-a^{(1/3)}}{1+x^{(1/3)}.a^{(1/3))}}, x>0,$ then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{(3x^{\frac{2}{3}})(1+x^2)}$


Wait, what does W.K.T means?

W.K.T means We know that

Please, do not answer very low-quality questions.

Notice that we can re-write this as $$y=\arctan(\tan(\arctan(x^{\frac{1}{3}})-\arctan(a^{\frac{1}{3}}))$$
This then simplifies to $\arctan(x^{\frac{1}{3}})-a^{\frac{1}{3}}$
Which can be derived easily using the chain rule
